# Why Writing Number in Text File Takes a Lot of Time?

Tags: python-3.x, time, streamwriter, binary-data

I have written a program that take 0.1092 seconds to generate a number but 787.26012 seconds =13 minute  to write that number (3.81 MB) in/on a text file, which is quite surprising, can anyone explain why that is happening? Also, is there a faster way to write that large number on a  text file?

```
import time
import sys
import math
start = time.time()

input_file="First1_58MB_enwik9.txt"
with open(input_file, "rb") as file: #--> open file in binary read mode
  byte_obj = file.read() #--> read all binary data
g=int.from_bytes( byte_obj, byteorder=sys.byteorder)
binary_dt=bin(g)


int_v=int(binary_dt,2)
length = math.ceil(math.log(int_v, 256))
res = int.to_bytes(int_v, length=length, byteorder='little', signed=False)

open("output_file_2.txt", "wb").write(res)

end = time.time()
print("Total time (in seconds) = ",(end - start))
#---------------------------
start = time.time()
with open("output_file_1.txt", 'w') as f:
  f.write('%d' % g)

end = time.time()
print("Total time (in seconds) = ",(end - start))
```

Comment: Fascinating! Presumably 99% of the time is spent in the implicit call to `g.__str__()`. Time how long it takes, just to be sure. I don't have an answer for you, but I imagine it would involve a highly optimised C/asm function that prints the number as a base 10 string to a very large preallocated buffer (`malloc` calls are expensive), and executed with `ctypes`).

Comment: So it turns out `'%d' % g` doesn't implicitly call `g.__str__()`, but it takes just as long.